# Recurrence function code which generates components using initial conditions

Tags: differential-equations, recursion

Please write a function which solve the follwoing equation in mathematica. Its urgent [image]

Comment: Please provide your Mathematica code to increase the chance to get helpful answer!

Comment: This is a complete equation, i want to solve in Mathematica but i dont know how we write it ,so please help for this.

Comment: You should provide some own effort. What did you try so far? Probably `Sum[]`, `KroneckerDelta[]` , `UnitStep[]`  might help you to create Mathematica code.

Comment: I completely solve this equations and reduce into a recurrece relations such as U[0]=0;
U[1]=1;
U[2]=0;
For K>=2
U[K+1]=(1/((k+1)^2))[(k-1)^2 U[k]+1/k!-(-1)^(k-1)/(k-1)!-1/(2(k-2)!)+(-1)^(k-2)/(2(k-2)!)] would you suggest the recurrece code for solving above equation which generate indiviudal components such as U[2], U[3], and so on

Comment: At first write the equation in Mathematica code. Depnding on `k`you need to define several conditions.

Answer (score 1):

First you should use `(..)`and not `[..]`. Then it is dangerous to use uppercase symbols as these are used by the system.

Further, your recurrence relation is a one step relation. Therefore you can only specify one single initial condition and not three. I choose `U[2]=0`:

```
eq = {
   u[2] == u2,
   u[k + 1] == (1/((k + 1)^2)) ((k - 1)^2 u[k] + 
       1/k! - (-1)^(k - 1)/(k - 1)! - 
       1/(2 (k - 2)!) + (-1)^(k - 2)/(2 (k - 2)!))
   };
RSolve[eq, u[k], k]
```

This results is an expression too long to display here.

Comment: This is a helping code. Thank you very much sir .

Comment: How we generate components of u[k] as a power series that is u[0]+xu[1]+x^2u[2]+...

Answer (score 0):

To generate a (finite) power series we may proceed as follows. As the recursion is only defined for k==2 upwards, we need to define k==0,1 separately. E.g. with `eq` from above

```
sol[0] = u0;
sol[1] = u1;
sol[k_] = u[k] /. RSolve[eq, u[k], k][[1]];
```

With this we may now define the power series, e.g.:

```
Sum[u[k] x^k, {k, 0, 4}] /. u[k_] :> sol[k]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.